# Why doesn't my Java application play the sound at each loop?

Tags: java, multithreading, audio, keystroke

I'm trying to make a **Java** application that simulates someone typing on their keyboard. The keystroke sound is played in a loop (**Java** chose a keystroke sound among others randomly and plays it) at a variable interval (to simulate a real person typing).

It works fine in the beginning, but after around the **95th** iteration, it stops playing the sound (while still looping) for less than 4 seconds then plays the sound again. And after the **160th** iteration, it plays the sound almost every second (instead of every third to sixth of a second).
After a while, it stops playing the sound for a long time, then forever.

Here is the source for the `AudioPlayer.java` class:

```java
package entity;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class AudioPlayer implements Runnable {
    private String audioFilePath;

    public void setAudioFilePath(String audioFilePath) {
         this.audioFilePath = audioFilePath;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        File audioFile = new File(audioFilePath);

        try {
            AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioFile);
            AudioFormat format = audioStream.getFormat();
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
            Clip audioClip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            audioClip.open(audioStream);
            audioClip.start();
            boolean playCompleted = false;
            while (!playCompleted) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    playCompleted = true;
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            audioClip.close();
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
            System.out.println("The specified audio file is not supported.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            System.out.println("Audio line for playing back is unavailable.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error playing the audio file.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the `Main.java` class to test the keystroke simulator:

```java
package sandbox;

import java.util.Random;

import entity.AudioPlayer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        AudioPlayer audio;

        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            int delay = rnd.nextInt(200)+75;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
            int index = rnd.nextInt(3)+1;
            audio = new AudioPlayer();
            audio.setAudioFilePath("resources/keystroke-0"+index+".wav");
            Thread thread = new Thread(audio);
            thread.start();
            System.out.println("iteration "+i);
        }
    }
}
```

I used multiple short (less than 200ms) wave files of different sounding keystrokes (3 in total) all in the resources directory.

**EDIT**

I read your answers and comments. And I'm thinking maybe I misundertood them because the suggested solutions don't work, or maybe I should have made myself clear on what I exactly wanted. Also, I need to note that I don't use threads often (and have no clue what a mutex is).

So I'll first explain what I exactly want the program to do. It should be able to simulate keystroke and so I used a Thread because it allows two keystroke sounds to overlap just like when a real person is typing. Basically the sound clips I am using are keystroke sounds and a keystroke sound is composed of two sounds:
the sound of a key being pressed.
the sound of a key being released.

If at some point the program allows two keystroke to overlap it will sound as if someone pressed one key then another and then released the first key. That's how really typing sounds like!

Now the issues I encountered using the proposed solutions are:
When calling the run() method of the AudioPlayer directly,

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Definitions here

    while (running) {
        Date previous = new Date();
        Date delay = new Date(previous.getTime()+rnd.nextInt(300)+75);

        // Setting the audio here

        audio.run();
        Date now = new Date();

        if (now.before(delay)) {
            try { 
                Thread.sleep(delay.getTime()-now.getTime());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

        System.out.println("iteration: "+(++i));
    }
}
```

the sounds play sequentially (one after the other) and at a rate that depends on the sleep duration of the AudioPlayer (or depends on the delay if the delay in the main() method is higher than the sleep duration of the AudioPlayer), which is no good because it won't sound like the average typist (more like someone who is new to typing and still looking for every keys when typing).

When calling the join() method of the AudioPlayer's Thread,

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Variable definitions here

    while (running) {
        int delay = rnd.nextInt(200)+75;
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie)
        {

        }

        //Setting the AudioPlayer and creating its Thread here

        thread.start();
        try
        {
            thread.join();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie)
        {

        }
        System.out.println("iteration "+(++i));
    }
}
```

the sounds play sequentially as well and at a rate that depends on the sleep duration of the AudioPlayer (or depends on the delay if the delay in the main() method is higher than the sleep duration of the AudioPlayer) which, again, is no good for the same reason as before.

So, to answer one of the commenter's question. Yes! there are other concerns not expressed before which require the threads in the first place.

I found a workaround that "solves" my issue (but that I don't consider as a proper solution since I am, in a way, cheating): What I did is increase the sleep duration of the AudioPlayer to something that is unlikely to be reached before the program is stopped (24 hours) and from what I've seen it doesn't use much resources even after more than an hour.

You can check out what I want, what I get when running the suggested solutions and what I get using my workaround on [this youtube videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBeyh8dQc3I&list=PLwXLXFJIj8kb-q7MJRzs20i5iKm5RhZYC) (Unfortunately StackOverflow doesn't have video uploading feature. so I had to put it on youtube).

**EDIT**
The sound effects can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10ULARYNczpWFp31VBs8HY6QxyZRevggJ/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Hello,

Since multi-threading depends on the amount of concurrent processes that can run at once on your computer, could it be that your computer runs out of CPU cores to run the threads that you start?

Comment: @user123 I don't know about that since, like I said, everything works fine until around the 95th iteration (and I don't have 95 physical or logical cores). Also, if I am not mistaken, the threads get removed by the garbage collector once they finished playing the sound.

Comment: @PaikuHan Sounds like a fun little project; but, multiple threads are not the way to guarantee consistent "wait...play...wait...play..." type behavior.  If you want that kind of behavior with multiple threads, you'll have to enforce the ordering with mutexes or other thread coordination tools, which is far too much effort unless there are other concerns not expressed here which require the threads in the first place.

Comment: It's not a matter of "running out of cores."  It's a matter of telling the OS that you have a bunch of independent tasks, and the hoping the OS has enough spare time to always schedule them consistently.  Eventually the OS won't schedule them consistently, and will think that's not a problem because they were presented as independent tasks.  Present the loop without a thread launcher in it, and it will give far better results.

Comment: @EdwinBuck I am now using a gaming loop style setup in my code but the threads are still needed. check the edit above. And if you have time maybe check out the videos they will give you a clearer understanding of what my issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this single-threaded solution which is a cleaner version of your own, but re-using already opened clips from buffers? To me the typing sounds pretty natural even though there are no two sounds playing at the same time. You can adjust the typing speed by changing the corresponding static constants in the `Application` class.

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q61159885;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine.Info;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream;
import static javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getLine;

public class AudioPlayer implements Closeable {
  private final Map<String, Clip> bufferedClips = new HashMap<>();

  public void play(String audioFilePath) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException {
    Clip clip = bufferedClips.get(audioFilePath);
    if (clip == null) {
      AudioFormat audioFormat = getAudioInputStream(new File(audioFilePath)).getFormat();
      Info lineInfo = new Info(Clip.class, audioFormat);
      clip = (Clip) getLine(lineInfo);
      bufferedClips.put(audioFilePath, clip);
      clip.open(getAudioInputStream(new File(audioFilePath)));
    }
    clip.setMicrosecondPosition(0);
    clip.start();
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
    bufferedClips.values().forEach(Clip::close);
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q61159885;

import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

public class Application {
  private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

  private static final int ITERATIONS = 10000;
  private static final int MINIMUM_WAIT = 75;
  private static final int MAX_RANDOM_WAIT = 200;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException {
    try (AudioPlayer audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer()) {
      for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
        sleep(MINIMUM_WAIT + RANDOM.nextInt(MAX_RANDOM_WAIT));
        audioPlayer.play(randomAudioFile());
      }
    }
  }

  private static void sleep(int delay) {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(delay);
    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
  }

  private static String randomAudioFile() {
    return "resources/keystroke-0" + (RANDOM.nextInt(3) + 1) + ".wav";
  }
}
```

You might have noticed that the `AudioPlayer` is `Closeable`, i.e. you can use "try with resouces" in the calling application. That way it makes sure that at the end of the program all clips are closed automatically.

The key to replaying the same clip is of course `clip.setMicrosecondPosition(0)` before you start.

---

**Update:** If you want to simulate multiple persons, just modify the main class like this. BTW, I don't know anything about audio programming and whether there is a way to better deal with mixers and overlapping sounds. It is just a proof of concept in order to give you an idea. There is one thread per person, but each person types in a serial fashion, not two keys at the same time. But multiple persons can overlap because there is one `AudioPlayer` per person with its own set of buffered clips.

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q61159885;

import java.util.Random;

public class Application {
  private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

  private static final int PERSONS = 2;
  private static final int ITERATIONS = 10000;
  private static final int MINIMUM_WAIT = 150;
  private static final int MAX_RANDOM_WAIT = 200;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int p = 0; p < PERSONS; p++)
      new Thread(() -> {
        try (AudioPlayer audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer()) {
          for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
            sleep(MINIMUM_WAIT + RANDOM.nextInt(MAX_RANDOM_WAIT));
            audioPlayer.play(randomAudioFile());
          }
        } catch (Exception ignored) {}
      }).start();
  }

  private static void sleep(int delay) {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(delay);
    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
  }

  private static String randomAudioFile() {
    return "resources/keystroke-0" + (RANDOM.nextInt(3) + 1) + ".wav";
  }
}
```

Comment: @kiregaex. it works but for some reasons the loop stops when ITERATION is higher like 1000000. But since it works longer than I need I choose your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the things EdwinBuck said, I believe you are doing way to much work in your AudioPlayer class (and every time). Try pre-create an AudioPlayer instance one time for all of your audio files (I believe it is 4?), and add a separate play() method, so that inside your loop you can do something like audioplayers[index].play().

Also note that in your AudioPlayer class you are waiting 500ms for the sound to finish which is longer than you wait to play the next sound. This will - after a while - lead to you running out of available threads... perhaps there's a callback you could use when the AudioClip is finished, instead of waiting.

Comment: this would make sense if it wasn't necessary for the audio playbacks to overlap. That's not the case here unfortunately.

Comment: after using a Linelistener on the Thread the issue I had disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

With threads, you are talking about independent flows of execution.  Your program is designed such that the picking of a delay an the playing of the sound are not independent.

something like

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        int delay = rnd.nextInt(200)+75;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {

        }
        int index = rnd.nextInt(3)+1;
        audio = new AudioPlayer();
        audio.setAudioFilePath("resources/keystroke-0"+index+".wav");
        audio.run();
        System.out.println("iteration "+i);
    }
```

Would express that you "wait" then "run a wav" then "repeat".

Right now you're relying on consistent scheduling of threads of execution on the cores to get the desired result; except that threads aren't intended to be the way to express consistent scheduling of execution.  Threads are intended to be the way to express independent scheduling of execution.

Odds are between your current wait and the current "play the wave" a few other things get in between, and with enough time, perhaps even the wav files could be played out-of-order.  I'd make the ordering explicit.

If you need good control on the timing within the loop, look to  a gaming loop type setup.  It's similar to your `for` loop, but looks like

```
while (running) {
  SomeTimeType previous = new TimeType();
  SomeTimeOffset delay = new TimeOffset(rnd.nextInt(200)+75);

  ...
  audio.run();
  SomeTimeType now = new TimeType();
  if (now.minus(offset).compareTo(previous) > 0) {
    try { 
      Thread.sleep(now.minus(offset).toMillis())
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
  }
}
```

The primary difference here is that your random delays start from the beginning of the wav file's play time to the beginning of the next wav file's play time, and there is no delay between files if the delay is shorter than the wav file's play time.

Also, I'd look into if the AudioPlayer can be reused between wave file playbacks, as that will probably get you even better results.

Now on the off chance you really need to keep the playing in a separate thread, you need to join the thread of the loop to the thread of the AudioPlayer to ensure that the AudioPlayer finishes before the loop thread advances.  Even though you are waiting a longer time in the for loop, remember, any process can come off the CPU core at any time, so your wait isn't an assurance that the for loop takes more time per iteration than the AudioPlayer takes per wav file, if the CPU had to handle something else (like a network packet).

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        int delay = rnd.nextInt(200)+75;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {

        }
        int index = rnd.nextInt(3)+1;
        audio = new AudioPlayer();
        audio.setAudioFilePath("resources/keystroke-0"+index+".wav");
        Thread thread = new Thread(audio);
        thread.start();
        thread.join();
        System.out.println("iteration "+i);
    }
```

The `thread.join()` will force the for loop to go into a sleep state (possibly shifting it off the CPU) until the audio thread completes.

Comment: Edwin, this is a sophisticated answer. But am I the only one here who thinks that for what the OP wants to do multi-threading is just not the right thing to do? A simple loop with synchronous execution is much easier and more resource-efficient. Why create 10,000 threads if you basically execute them sequentially, always waiting for thread n to finish before starting thread n+1? Besides, with just 3 different audio files I would even re-use those as much as possible and just play them again.

Comment: IMO multi-threading is only necessary if I want to simulate several persons typing simultaneously, each one having their own typing rhythms. Then I would use one thread per person and could easily parametrise the program to set the number of persons for the simulation. But unless it should happen that typing sounds overlap, each person is a synchronous thread and for n=1 I don't need to start any threads. But the OP did not describe in detail what exactly he wants to simulate.

Comment: @kriegaex You're not the only one, that's why I said there should be one thread of execution for the sounds and delays (however they are ordered).  Now if you want to have multiple sound like they are typing, then you'd probably want one thread per simulated person (assuming the audio players can mix properly for output).

Comment: @kriegaex you are both wrong. when someone is typing fast, one can press a key then another and then release the first key. I should have mentioned that each of the sound effects used are the sound of a key pressed then released (all in less than 150 ms) so playing another sound effects almost simultaneously will make it sound like one key is pressed then another then the first one is released then the second. check my edit of the question.

Comment: Well, @PaikuHan, I would not say that either of us was wrong but you did not describe the use case well enough - which resulted in lots of unnecessary effort and cycles for discussion. Like so often in life, requirements engineering als works by the rule "garbage in, garbage out".

Comment: The updated question is now easier to understand. I like to add to what I just said that it is always a good idea to explain **what** exactly you want to achieve and not to focus on **how** you think it should be done (e.g. using threads the way you did or using threads at all). This is called the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898). One request because it is a fun puzzle to play with: Can you share your typing sounds for download somewhere so I and others can play around with your code and have audio feedback too? We might come up with a nice solution for you.

Comment: @kriegaex yeah sorry about that. What I meant was you misunderstood my original post (because it was incomplete). Also I added the sound effects in the original question.

Comment: @PaikuHan Having taken typing as a class, I can assure you that typists who want non-garbage output may type really, really fast, but the letters are not pressed simultaneously, even for modifier keys like "Shift A" and "Ctrl C".  Also, unless you want to just hear the answer, "you're absolutely right, there's no possible improvement" you sometimes need to entertain other solutions as possibly being right, until they are obviously wrong.  My no-thread between the key and delay simulates a single person typing; which means you would launch one thread per typist, with overlapping sounds.

Comment: @EdwinBuck it seems you are right (I tried "Ctrl A" with one finger from each hand as fast as I can and it actually selected the whole text). But the one other issue still remains: The audio files have a specific length (less than 150ms from when the key is press to when it is released) and I can't shorten it to make it look like the user is typing faster. so making sounds overlap seem to be the best solution. Also, I could be wrong but I think I've implemented your suggestions properly and the typing effect was slower than when multithreading.

Comment: @PaikuHan It probably is a bit slower, and that's why I suggested putting the delays relative to the start of the playing the audio clips.  Also you might want to be sure the audio clips are very short.  Finally, most professional recording studios (my brother wanted me to help him make a film once, it's a long story) don't do this.  They actually use per-recorded clips, and mix them to make them seem like they are new.  If you listen closely, most of the sounds from different shows are actually the same recordings, layered.

Comment: @EdwinBuck OK. I could be wrong here but with your suggested solutions (or, as far as I know, with any non threaded solution) even if I put the delays relative to the start of the playing the audio clips, I would still have to wait for the instruction that calls for the audio playback to be done before any other instruction could be executed and with a "key pressed/key released" sound of about 128 ms it will have a word/min limit (i.e. I won't for instance be able to simulate someone typing at 100 wpm if I wanted to).

Comment: @EdwinBuck Also, as you might have figured out, I do want to use the typing simulator on a video (on educational videos to be more precise) and since I'm not an audio engineer , sound designer or soundFX guy, it would be to much of a hassle for me to add keystroke sounds on the videos. And it wouldn't feel real I think (not synchronized with each character appearing on the video). So it's definitely not a possibility for me.

Comment: @PaikuHan Look into video editing tools.  They have a sound bar where you drag and drop sounds files (represented as rectangles) into one of a few sound channels (non overlapping voices of sound).  I get that you are not a sound engineer, but since you'll be doing the job, you will be a sound engineer despite your experience.  I'd watch a few youtube videos. IMovie is a great place to start.  For sound, experiment with layering sounds to make a "sound scene" one voice is not enough.  And it's easier to sync sound with video when they're both there.

Comment: @EdwinBuck I will look into it!

Answer (score 0):

The library [AudioCue](https://github.com/philfrei/AudioCue) was made for exactly this sort of thing. You might try running the "frog pond" demo, simulating a number of frogs all croaking, all generated from a single frog croak recording.

You can take a single typewriter click and run everything from it, create a cue with, say 10 simultaneous overlaps allowed. Then use an RNG to pick which of the 10 "cursors" to click. The 10 typists can each have their own volume & pan location, and can be pitched slightly differently so that it sounds like the typewriters are different models or the keys are being hit with different weights (as if an old manual typewriter).

One can tweak RNG algorithms for the different typing speeds (using varying sleep times).

For myself, I wrote an event system where the play commands are queued up on an event system using a `ConcurrentSkipListSet`, where the stored objects include a timing value (milliseconds after a given zero point) that is used for sorting as well as controlling when the play gets executed. That might be overkill if you don't intend to do this sort of thing very often.